# Woocommerce - Proceed to checkout button not showing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shopping-cart

I'm making my first WooCommerce website, but I found a problem that I couldn't resolve, and Google didn't help me either.
My problem is that when I'm on the shopping cart page and I only have one kind of product, the "proceed to checkout" button is not there, and when I add another kind of product it appears, I will show a gift to illustrate this better

[image: GIF of the problem]

As you can see, when there are two different kinds of items on the cart, the button is there, but when I remove one it disappears. I'm sure I changed one setting accidentally or something, but now I can't find. If anyone could help me with this I would highly appreciate it. Thank You.

Comment: Which theme you are using?

Comment: I have the default one, storefront

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, it was a conflict of a plugin (mercado pago) with a template.